# pymysql SELECT * only detecting changes made externally after instantiating a new connection

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have two applications that access the same DB. One application inserts data into a table. The other sits in a loop and waits for the data to be available. If I add a new connection and close the connection before I run the SELECT query I find the data in the table without issues. I am trying to reduce the number of connections. I tried to leave the connection open then just loop through and send the query. When I do this, I do not get any of the updated data that was inserted into the table since the original connection was made. I get I can just re-connect and close, but this is a lot of overhead if I am connecting and closing every second or 2. Any ideas how to get data that was added to a DB from an external source with a SELECT query without having to connect and close every time in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Do you commit your insert?
normally the best way is you close your connection, and it is not generating very overhead if you open a connection for the select query.

Comment: Yes, the inserts from the application that adds the data to the DB is committing. I can also see the data in the DB using phpmyadmin.